# Can no longer convert between std::unique_ptr<Derived> to std::unique_ptr<Base>

Tags: c++, nlohmann-json

So I have an issue in converting between a base and derived class after adding some code to (de)serialize for JSON. I am using the nlohmann JSON library. For background, here is the general original set up (before the JSON code):

```
class Base;
class Derived : public Base;

std::unique_ptr<Derived> Foo(Node x) {
  std::unique_ptr<Derived> result;
  /* Set some fields */
  return result;
}


std::unique_ptr<Base> NodeToBase(Node x) {
  std::unique_ptr<Base> result = nullptr;

  switch (x->type):
    case (SomeType):
      result = Foo(x);

  return result;
}
```

Before adding the changes, the following assertions worked:

```
static_assert(std::is_convertible<Derived*, Base*>::value);
static_assert(std::is_convertible<std::unique_ptr<Derived>, std::unique_ptr<Base>>::value);
```

Next, I added some serialization functions to my base and derived classes as such:

```
class Base {

  virtual nlohmann::json ToJson() const;
  virtual void FromJson(const nlohmann::json &j);

}

class Derived : public Base {

  nlohmann::json ToJson() const override;
  void FromJson(const nlohmann::json &j) override;
}
```

I also removed any `const` quantifiers on member variables in `Base` and `Derived` to allow for deserialization.

And now, after compiling, the `static_assert`'s above no longer worked, and I get the following error.

```
foo.cpp:155:14: error: no viable overloaded '='
      result = Foo(x);
      ~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/llvm@6/6.0.1/include/c++/v1/memory:2347:28: note: candidate function (the implicit copy assignment operator) not viable: no known conversion from 'unique_ptr<Derived, default_delete<Derived>>' to 'const unique_ptr<Base, default_delete<Base>>' for 1st argument
class _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS unique_ptr {
                           ^
/usr/local/Cellar/llvm@6/6.0.1/include/c++/v1/memory:2463:15: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'unique_ptr<Derived, default_delete<Derived>>' to 'unique_ptr<Base, default_delete<Base>>' for 1st argument
  unique_ptr& operator=(unique_ptr&& __u) _NOEXCEPT {
              ^
/usr/local/Cellar/llvm@6/6.0.1/include/c++/v1/memory:2555:15: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'std::unique_ptr<Derived>' to 'std::nullptr_t' (aka 'nullptr_t') for 1st argument
  unique_ptr& operator=(nullptr_t) _NOEXCEPT {
              ^
/usr/local/Cellar/llvm@6/6.0.1/include/c++/v1/memory:2474:15: note: candidate template ignored: requirement 'is_convertible<typename unique_ptr<Derived, default_delete<Derived> >::pointer, pointer>::value' was not satisfied [with _Up = Derived, _Ep = std::__1::default_delete<Derived>]
  unique_ptr& operator=(unique_ptr<_Up, _Ep>&& __u) _NOEXCEPT {
              ^
```

Any help would be appreciated. The only workaround I've found that works is to replace:

`result = Foo(x);`

with

`result = std::unique_ptr<Base>(reinterpret_cast<Base *>(Foo(x).release()));`

Comment: The code shown does not generate the errors show.  Actually ensure the exact code you post generates the exact errors you post; else, mindreading required.  [Mcve]

Comment: Did you move code around? [`is_convertible`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible) requires complete types, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Your workaround uses reinterpret cast, that even succeeds when you don't want it. Try using static_cast instead

Comment: With `class Derived : public Base;` are you trying to forward declare the inheritance?